# How do I get an event to fire every time a link is clicked (using JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, events

I'm trying to fire an event every time a navigation link (a.nav) is clicked.  For Safari, it works as expected; however, in every other browser it ONLY fires the first time a link is clicked.  For some reason, I'm not getting the desire result, is there anything I'm missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PatrickCason.com</title>

<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #main, #namespace {
            padding-right: 115px;
        }

        #textarea {
            padding-right: 115px;
            padding-top: 15px;
        }

        #social {
            bottom: 82px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="spritely.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#main").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
        $("#copyright").show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 500);
        $("#main").effect("bounce", { times: 1, distance: 5 }, 250);

        $('a.nav').live('click', function() {
            //For some reason... this only works with the first time I click a nav link... herein lies the problem!
            $('#spark').sprite({fps: 30, no_of_frames: 12, play_frames: 12});
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="floater"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="spark"></div>
            <div id="namespace"><span style="font-size: 20px;">hi.  i am </span><h1 style="display: inline;  font-size: 36px;">Patrick Cason</h1><span style="font-size: 20px;">.</span></div>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#contact" class="nav">Contact Me!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about" class="nav">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#links" class="nav">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog/" target="_blank" class="nav">Blog</a></li>
                </ul><br>
                <p><b>Phone:</b><br><span style="font-size: 24px;  font-weight: bold;">615.339.4300</span></p>
                <p><b>Email:</b><br><a href="#contact" class="nav">pcason@comcast.net</a></p>
            </div>
            <div id="social">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/mntlinstituteflr" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/cereallarceny" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/patrick-cason/1a/bb5/229" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin.png"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/feed.png"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="home"><a href="#home" class="nav"><img src="images/home.png"></a></div>            
            <div id="textarea">
                <div id="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="shadow"></div>
        <script>
            $(window).load(function () {
                $("#shadow").fadeIn(1250);
            });
        </script>
        <div id="copyright">
            Copyright &copy; 2011 Patrick Cason.  All rights reserved.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I'm not being to vague... I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: What event do you want to fire?

Comment: Ahh, I want to fire the #spark event using the JQuery Spritely plugin.

Comment: What is .sprite() by the way? it gives me an error.

Comment: It's from the Spritely library:

www.spritely.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the need for using `live()` in your case. That is for when you have dynamically added html. Or, when you have a decent number of elements that will bind to the same event handler (rather than click() which would bind individual handlers for each link).

```
$('a').click(function() {
            $('#spark').sprite({fps: 30, no_of_frames: 12, play_frames: 12});
        });
```

I think the problem might be your selector. Try just selecting `<a>` tags

http://jsfiddle.net/EmvQk/

EDIT:

Edit your code to comment out the sprite() method and add an alert() as indicated in the comments below. I am pretty confident the problem is stemming from the sprite() call and this little test will determine if that is the case.

Your Css needs to follow the set of rules that the library requires in order to function properly. After reviewing the library example and based on your `#sprite` css rule ... Try making these changes:

```
#sprite 
{           
background: transparent url(images/spark.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 223px;
width: 156px;
height: 567px;
z-index: 2000;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I was actually using click beforehand, that did not work either.  I have tried it both as 'a' and 'a.nav'.  Both with the same results of only going through once.

Comment: I am using JQuery AJAX as well as the JQuery History plugin.  Would this be the reason for any problems?

Comment: @cereallarceny that tells me you have a different problem. I double checked and my approach works just fine with <a> tags. Check out the jsfiddle to see. http://jsfiddle.net/EmvQk/  Do you have other relevant code to post?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to link you to a temporary host of the full site:  http://playerwebsite.pcriot.com/personal/

Comment: I disagree. If you have a lot of links (I'd argue, already more than 10), then using `live` or `delegate` is much better than attaching an event handler to every link.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It also could be that your sprite() method could be part of the problem. Comment out the sprite code and put an alert("Test") line. That will tell you if its the prob or not

Comment: @Matthew Cox I indeed tried that, here is my attempt: http://pastie.org/2108137

I was preceded by the same result, it only fired once (even the alert dialog only fired once).

Comment: @Felix Kling You should provide analysis data for making such arguments. This firebug profiling output disagrees with you http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/event-delegation-jquery-performance/

Comment: @Cereallarceny Your code snippet doesn't have the sprite() method commented out. Is this just a typo or did you forget to comment it out and test it?

Comment: @Matthew Cox Ahh!  Thank you.  YES, THE ALERT FIRES EVERY TIME!  I suppose now the error is not due to the handler but to the spritely plugin.  Could it be the way my CSS is styled?

Comment: @MatthewCox: I'm not necessarily talking about performance. But I'm sure you get better results if you use `delegate` and bind the event handler to closest common parent. Maybe 10 was a bit too optimistic. But the more elements you have, the more attractive becomes event delegation. I mostly disagree with that it is only for dynamically generated elements.

Comment: @Cereallarceny Possibly. Post your CSS so we can analyze.

Comment: @Felix Kling I'll concede that too many links would be better served by a delegate rather than individual handlers. I only saw 9-10 links so I didn't see much of a optimization advantage here with such a low number. But much beyond that, it is clearly a better solution.

Comment: @Matthew Cox Sorry, here's the whole CSS document, that may help: http://pastie.org/2108189

Comment: @cereallarceny Try changing the #sprite CSS definition to what I put in my edit above. See how that works.

Comment: @Matthew Cox Sadly I tried your CSS definition and couldn't get the required result.  I figured that z-index was what I was missing so I tried the results both with and without the cursor ruling, neither with success.  Are we sure I'm doing the correct calling of the sprite method?

Comment: When I run through FireBug, I get an error after clicking a link, here's what's going on:

$("#spark").sprite is not a function
[Break On This Error] $('#spark').sprite({fps: 30, no_of_frames: 12, play_frames: 12});

Comment: @cereallarceny well that is certainly a problem. You must not have the plugin properly working because it doesn't recognize the method.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with Spritely, as of version 0.5 they have a destroy() method, so...

```
$("#spark").click(function() {
var $spark = $("#spark");
$coil.sprite({
fps: 30, 
no_of_frames: 12, 
on_last_frame: function(obj) {
    obj.spStop(); // stop the animation on the last frame
        obj.spState(1);
        killSprite($spark);
    }
});
});

function killSprite(yourEl){
yourEl.destroy();
}
```

I popped the destroy method in a function that is called on the last frame of your animation so hopefully it won't cause any issues

Answer (score 0):

It should be that

```
$('#spark').sprite({fps: 30, no_of_frames: 12, play_frames: 12});
```

in and of itself doesn't work multiple times. Have you tried calling that function twice and see what happens.

To test if your click handler is the culprit, add an alert to the click handler and see if the issue is your click handler or the code snipped above.

Comment: Well I added an alert... and it still only appeared once.  To be sure we're on the same page, here's the code I tried:

http://pastie.org/2108137

Comment: Can you post your case on jsfiddle.net and we can take a look at it there.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  I forgot to comment out the spritely line of code when trying (silly me).  The alert does show everytime.  I wonder then if it's because of my CSS that is preventing it to launch each time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem may be with the spritely plugin for jQuery.  I set up a quick test at: http://jsfiddle.net/Htm4y/, that worked for me (in Chrome).  In the example, clicking the .nav links fires a jQuery toggle.  I would need to see your css to figure out what is supposed to be in that div, but it must be configured correctly in order for spritely to animate it.